# Planning Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not really sure if the questions that ask for opinion are allowed here, but I'll give it a try, as it seems pretty logical to ask for advise when my own search didn't produce any desirable result.

I'm building a new application and it seems like doing a website mockup is a pretty good idea. I couldn't find any free software that does a decent job in that regard, so I would appreciate any pointers. Pencil project as a firefox plugin seemed like a good one, but it hangs on exporting created documents.

Any other ideas for a software that is used for application planning and mockups would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're not sure what kind of question you should ask, take a look at the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I'm not sure we could reasonably answer this.  It may be a better question for http://superuser.com since StackOverflow is only programming related

Comment: @iWasRobbed - Stack Overflow isn't a bad venue since it's about "software tools commonly used by programmers," as listed in the FAQ. However, it doesn't really fit the standard Q/A format as it stands.

Comment: @derekerdmann Agree to disagree.  Programmers don't "commonly" do mockups, designers do.  This is also a good question for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com by the way.

Comment: Sometimes the designer and programmer have to be the same person... mockups are great for focusing on the task. PLus, he said application, so it could be a web application, in which case, the form design is more important than graphic design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the web demo of [Balsamiq Mockups](http://builds.balsamiq.com/b/mockups-web-demo/) for free...